# Tosafos Amud in Sanhedrin?

Tags: maseches-sanhedrin, tosfot

I heard that there was an Amud in Sanhedrin that's almost entirely a Tosafos. I've heard stories about Gedolim on this Amud and I wanted to see the Amud for myself.

What is this Amud?

Comment: There are many pieces of Talmud Bavli (whether it be a few lines or a whole page or perhaps more) that were added in later, some as late as the rishonim.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/61690/massacre-of-baalei-tosafos.

Comment: ^^^^^^refers to Tosafot in Bava Kamma, and the legend surrounding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you seek is [Bava Kama 77a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=21&daf=77&format=pdf):

[image: Image of Bava Kama 77a]

Nine words of Gemara text.

Three lines of Rashi.

And a whole lotta' Tosfos!

---

The shortest-text amud in Sanhedrin (other than the final page) is [9a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=9&format=pdf). But that doesn't come close.

Comment: Tosfot concerning Tum'at Ochlim if I remember

Answer (score 1):

Here is an amud in Nazir (33b) thats entirely Tosafos. With no Gemora or Rashi at all
[image: דף לג:]

Comment: Thank you! I suspect a lot more of today's yeshivas have covered Bava Kama [or parts thereof] than Nazir, hence there may be more folklore about the Bava Kama one. But this is amazing! (There's the story that Nazir was the mesechta R' Elchanan Wasserman hadn't yet learned when the Chofetz Chaim told a crowd "people could miss something like Nazir!")

Comment: The beauty of Daf Hayomi in depth with reviewing 5 times... :)